# Share all Picasa web albums with other users

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I know it's possible to share individual albums but is it possible to share them all?

All the photos that me and my girlfriend have are stored on my Picasa account but she'd like access too.

Answer (score 1):

At this stage, this isn't possible, though it has been requested a lot on the 
[Picasa help pages](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/search.py?query=share%20all%20albums&btnG=Search%20Help&ctx=en%3asearchbox).

Comment: No problem. I would love this functionality too and it seems so simple, I don't know why it hasn't been done yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a secret link for either your Public or Unlisted Albums.
http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173224

(Thanks to Jeremy Simon for posting the link to the help file. I guess they updated it since he first posted).

> Click on **Public Gallery** or **Unlisted Gallery** on the **My Photos tab** to
>   find a single, unchanging URL to share all of your albums with friends
>   and family. Public Gallery
>
> People who visit your public gallery URL -
>   picasaweb.google.com/username - can view all of your public albums,
>   plus any albums that you've explicitly shared with them. Unlisted
>   Gallery
>
> People who visit your unlisted gallery URL will see all of your public
>   albums, all albums set to a visibility of 'Limited, anyone with the
>   link,' as well as any albums that you've explicitly shared with them.
>   This gallery includes a unique authorization key in the web address;
>   the key is a combination of letters and numbers that make the address
>   difficult to guess.

Comment: I tried Clay Nichols answer but when I sent the URL to another PC here at home and clicked on it Picasa Web said it couldn't find the page. All my albums are Unlisted and Visibility is set to Limited on all of them.

Comment: Hmmm... it works for me.
I followed the instructions, copied the URL and pasted it into a different browser that was NOT logged into Google/Picasa. Pictures came up just fine.

Answer (score 0):

At this point it's not possible, but there is a way to do that a little bit faster, that going into individual albums and sharing them.

1. Go to your **Google+**
2. Go to **Photos**
3. Choose **Your Albums**
4. Click on **Change how your albums are shared**

From there you'll see a list of your albums and you can easily change the visibility of each album much faster.

[image: Sharing your albums in Google Photos]